# How to join tables on 2 foreign keys without duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join these 3 tables, keeping all the values (even `null`). How can I do it without dupicates?

```
hotel (hid, name, town)
room (hid, num, type)
booking (hid, cid, dstart, ndays, room)
```

`room.hid` is a foreign key to `hotel.hid`.

`booking (hid, room)` is a foreign key to `room (hid, num)`.

Here is `hotel` table:

```
hid     name    town
-----------------------
H001    Hamlets London
H002    Baileys London
H003    Stevens Kent
H004    Hamlets Kent
```

Here is `room` table:

```
hid     num type
------------------
H001    1   Double
H001    2   Single
H002    1   Double
H003    1   Single
```

Here is `booking` table:

```
hid     cid     dstart      ndays   room
----------------------------------------
H001    C001    2019-07-18  5       1
H001    C001    2019-06-20  3       2
H001    C002    2018-06-01  5       1
```

I have already joined the `booking` table with `hotel` table using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel h FULL JOIN booking b ON h.hid = b.hid
```

Here are the results for that query:

```
hid     name    town    hid     cid     dstart      ndays   room
----------------------------------------------------------------
H001    Hamlets London  H001    C001    2019-07-18  5       1
H001    Hamlets London  H001    C001    2019-06-20  3       2
H001    Hamlets London  H001    C002    2018-06-01  5       1
H003    Stevens Kent    null    null    null        null    null    
H002    Baileys London  null    null    null        null    null                    
H004    Hamlets Kent    null    null    null        null    null
```

How do I join the `room` table as well but keeping the `null` values?

Comment: What does "without duplicates" mean? Or "join the room table as well but keeping the null values"? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Part of a [mcve] is a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you do not give one. You don't even give an example for us guess what that is.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring in the `room` table, you ca, simply add a `LEFT JOIN` to the query. This will not filter out records that have no booking information:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hotel h 
FULL JOIN booking b ON h.hid = b.hid
LEFT JOIN room r ON r.hid = b.hid AND r.num = b.room
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYCK3WcWUs386wwCnSEefc/0)**:

```
| hid  | name    | town   | hid  | cid  | dstart                   | ndays | room | hid  | num | type   |
| ---- | ------- | ------ | ---- | ---- | ------------------------ | ----- | ---- | ---- | --- | ------ |
| H001 | Hamlets | London | H001 | C001 | 2019-07-18T00:00:00.000Z | 5     | 1    | H001 | 1   | Double |
| H001 | Hamlets | London | H001 | C002 | 2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 5     | 1    | H001 | 1   | Double |
| H001 | Hamlets | London | H001 | C001 | 2019-06-20T00:00:00.000Z | 3     | 2    | H001 | 2   | Single |
| H002 | Baileys | London |      |      |                          |       |      |      |     |        |
| H003 | Stevens | Kent   |      |      |                          |       |      |      |     |        |
| H004 | Hamlets | Kent   |      |      |                          |       |      |      |     |        |
```